How to get element geometry in web-ifc?
I'm using web-ifc version 0.0.59 to explore IFC files.
I'm also using @thatopen/components and associated packages but I find it easier to use the web-ifc package to explore the structure and element relationships.
Now, I'm trying to get the geometry (vertices and indices) of ifc elements like IfcSlab or IfcColumn like following:
const geomPtrObj = ifcApi.GetGeometry(modelId, itemId) as any
const vertices = ifcApi.GetVertexArray(geomPtrObj.$$.ptr, 10)
console.log(vertices)

This doesn't seem to work. It returns a Float32Array with all zero entries.
What I'm trying achieve is to draw a 2d floor plan from all the elements linked to a building floor / storey. @thatopen/component does have a floor plan generator but that doesn't have all the details I need - so I'm looking for a way to get the geometries of elements and draw it myself.
